# Can't properly pass error information from my NextJS API route

Tags: next.js, swr, nextjs-api-router

created the default project using `npx create-next-app@latest`

src/pages/index.tsx

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

export default function Home() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/hello', fetcher,{
    onSuccess: async (data) => {
      console.log('we got a success');
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log('we got an error');
    }
  });
  console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
  console.log(`isLoading: ${JSON.stringify(isLoading)}`);
  return (
  <></>
  )
}
```

src/pages/api/hello.tsx

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  res.status(400).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
  //res.status(400).end();
}
```

With the code above I'm getting the log from the `onSuccess` method, console prints that we have data (name: 'John Doe') and error is `undefined`.
If comment the line with `json({...})` and uncomment the one with `.end()` I get the log from `onError` but I can't pass any additional information.
Seems like any send method of `NextApiResponse` like `json()` or `send()` result in invocation of the `onSuccess`.

I want to be able to send JSON object in case of an error and `onSuccess` or `onError` to be called accordingly to the status passed to `res.status()`.
What am I missing?